# Object column with "main" and float numbers to non float numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Hope someone can help me
I have

| Number | Object |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | main |
| Name2 | 490348,0 |
| Name3 | 237928,0 |

df type is object für column "Object"
I need to get rid of the float numbers and turn them into int numbers.
But I get an error "cannot convert float NaN to integer".

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `pd.to_numeric()`+`np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

s=pd.to_numeric(df['Object'].replace(',','',regex=True),errors='coerce')
df['Object']=np.where(s.notna(),s.fillna(0).astype(int),df['Object'])
```

output of `df`:

```
    Number  Object
0   Name1   main
1   Name2   490348
2   Name3   237928
```

Now you can check the dtype of `df['Object']`:

```
df['Object'].map(type)

#output:

0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
Name: Object, dtype: object
```

**Note:** It is not a good idea to have a column of different dtypes

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that this deletes the "main" that I need in the rows where there is no number.

Comment: @Dilan updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**